# React input not updating when receiving props

Tags: forms, reactjs

**Fix**

Add this method for the first time that the element is rendered, it has access to the `props` received right away.

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (typeof this.props.options.value !== "undefined")
    this.setState({value: this.props.options.value})
},
```

I have several react elements that are almost working as intended. I have a view with a list of elements and a modal view to edit them. When the edit button of an element is clicked, the element is set on the state as selected, and the modal form is shown (it is passed the element as a prop).

```
showUpdateForm(poiIndex) {
  this.setState({selectedPoi: this.state.pois[poiIndex]})
  $('#updatePoiModal').modal('show')
  console.log('shown')
},

...render()...
<UpdatePoiForm poi={this.state.selectedPoi} ref="updatePoiForm" successHandler={this.successUpdateHandler}/>
```

When an item is clicked the modal view is displayed correctly, however, the text values passed are not displayed; the ones from the previous selected element are shown (or empty boxes if it is the first element clicked). Here is the render method of the modal view:

```
render() {
  console.log('rendering')
  if(!this.props.poi)
    return null
  console.log(this.props.poi.name)
  var poi = this.props.poi

  var config = {
    url: `${context.apiUrl}user/pois/${poi.id}`,
    method: 'PUT',
    successMessage: 'El Punto de Interés fue actualizado',
    successHandler: this.successHandler,
    hideSubmitButton: true,
    fields: {
      name: {
        label: 'Nombre',
        type: 'text',
        value: this.props.poi.name
      },
      location: {
        label: 'Ubicación',
        type: 'text',
        display: false,
        value: this.props.poi.location
      },
      category_id: {
        label: 'Categoría',
        type: 'select',
        options: context.poi_categories.map((cat) => {
          return {value: cat.id, desc: cat.name}
        })
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Row>
        <Col size="12">
          <Panel>
            <PanelBody>
              <FormComponent config={config} ref="form"/>
            </PanelBody>
          </Panel>
        </Col>
        <Col size="12">
          <Panel>
            <PanelHeading heading="Selecciona la ubicación" />
            <Map height="400px" ref="map_update_poi" zoom="15"/>
          </Panel>
        </Col>

      </Row>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here is the render method of the form component:

```
render() {
  elems = []
  count = 0

  for (var key in this.props.config.fields) {
    console.log(this.props.config.fields[key])
    var _type = this.props.config.fields[key].type
    var config = {
      key: count++,
      options: this.props.config.fields[key],
      ref: key,
      refName: key,
      fullWidth: this.props.config.fullWidth,
    }

    switch (_type) {
      case 'text':
        elems.push(<InputElement {...config}/>)
        break
      case 'select':
        elems.push(<SelectElement {...config}/>)
        break
      case 'multipleSelect':
        elems.push(<MultipleSelectElement {...config}/>)
        break
      case 'button':
        elems.push(<ButtonElement {...config}/>)
        break
      case 'switcher':
        elems.push(<SwitcherElement {...config}/>)
        break
      case 'timePicker':
        elems.push(<TimePickerElement {...config}/>)
        break
      case 'radio':
        elems.push(<RadioElement {...config}/>)
        break
      case 'autocomplete':
        elems.push(<AutoCompleteInputElement {...config}/>)
        break
    }
  }
  console.log(elems)

  return (
    <form action="#" className="form-horizontal">
      <div className="form-content">
        {elems}
        {!this.props.config.hideSubmitButton ? <div className="form-buttons">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
              <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSave}
                      className="btn btn-blue btn-ripple">Crear</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> : null}
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}
```

And the render method of the input element  (removed variable declarations for brevity, none are missing):

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className={formClass} style={style}>
      <label className="control-label col-md-3">{this.props.options.label}</label>
      <div className={inputClass}>
        <div className="inputer">
          <div className="input-wrapper">
            <input ref={this.props.refName} type="text" className="form-control" onFocus={this.props.onFocus}
              placeholder={this.props.placeholder} value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </div>
          {validationMsg}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Lastly, I am checking the input props here:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  console.log('input element', nextProps)
  if (typeof this.props.options.value !== "undefined")
    this.setState({value: this.props.options.value})
},
```

I have added log statements in every "stop" of the chain. The modal view shows the element correctly, the form shows the strings of the last element clicked, and the props of the input element also show information of the most recently clicked element. However, when input is rendered, `this.state.value` is null (which is the value given in getInitialState()) or the value of the previous element. According to the order of logs, the props are received before rendering. While I understand that state updates are not immediate, if the render happened, then the change in state should trigger render again, with the correct values this time, but it is not happening and I don't understand why!

```
shown
list index 1
name Object { label="Nombre",  type="text"}
location Object { label="Ubicación",  type="text",  display=false}
category_id Object { label="Categoría",  type="select",  options=[2]}
[Object { key="0",  ref="name",  props={...},  more...}, Object { key="1",  ref="location",  props={...},  more...}, Object { key="2",  ref="category_id",  props={...},  more...}]
input props Object { options={...},  refName="name",  fullWidth=undefined}
render input null
input props Object { options={...},  refName="location",  fullWidth=undefined}componentWillReceiveProps    index.js (line 35220)
render input null
** At this point the new element is received **
** The objects didn't paste completely, but the correct values are 
   there this time. However, there is no output from componentWillReceiveProps **
new poi test02
rendering update form
update form test02
name Object { label="Nombre",  type="text",  value="test02"}
location Object { label="Ubicación",  type="text",  display=false,  more...}
category_id Object { label="Categoría",  type="select",  options=[2]}
[Object { key="0",  ref="name",  props={...},  more...}, Object { key="1",  ref="location",  props={...},  more...}, Object { key="2",  ref="category_id",  props={...},  more...}]
2 render input null
Object { category="Almacen",  category_id=1,  id=627,  more...}
```

**Edit 2:**
Now this problem only occurs on the first click. Happened when I replaced `this.props` for nextProps per @Radio- 's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `componentWillReceiveProps`, set the state to nextProps.options.value instead of this.props.options.value

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (typeof nextProps.options.value !== "undefined")
    this.setState({value: nextProps.options.value})
},
```

If it's on the first render, `componentWillReceiveProps` isn't called, so you can use `componentDidMount` with this.props to achieve the same:

```
componentDidMount() {
   if (typeof this.props.options.value !== "undefined")
   this.setState({value: this.props.options.value})
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that mistake. However, the problem persists. The render is not being triggered after the props are set with the chosen element. I will edit the question to include console output.

Comment: I didn't notice before, but that change fixed the issue for every click after the first. The first one still has the problem

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps doesn't get called on the first render. You would need to use componentWillMount or have an initial state that works by default

Comment: Does `componentWillMount ` have the props accessible? Although, since it is the same view every time, the first render happens with no information for values, it is the second render that gives me problems.

Comment: No, it doesn't. You could set the value of the input to state.value if it's not null, otherwise set it to props.options.value. Or, what is more usual, just pass in the next value as a prop.

Comment: What you said about the first time not calling `componentWillReceiveProps` finally clicked! Adding the `componentDidMount` function using the same logic made it work. Thank you so much! Can you edit your answer with the function to accept it? (I added it to the question)

Comment: As of React 16.3 you should no longer be using ```componentWillReceiveProps``` as it has been deprecated. You can read more about it here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops